# jQuery: open window and attach a submit() callback to the opened window's document form

Tags: jquery, callback, window, form-submit

Hey, on a page I have a link which opens up a new window displaying a form.

```
function open_window(href)
{
   win = window.open(href, '', 'width=300, height=400');

   $(win.document).ready(function() {  
      $(win.document).contents().find("#links_form").submit(function(){alert(77);});
   });      
}
```

But when I press the submit button nothing's happening but if I put the same line of code

```
$(win.document).contents().find("#links_form").submit(function(){alert(77);});
```

in the firebug console (main window) everything works and the submit() callback attaches itself. What am I missing?

Comment: I trust that `href` points to a location on the same domain, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(win.document).contents()
```

Change to

```
this.contents()
```

win isn't available inside the ready function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I replace I get the error: this.contents is not a function.

And if I put $(this) no errors occurrs but it still doesn't work

Comment: Haven't tried, but now I'm using $(win.document.getElementById("form")); and it works